# Showing Discount labels for products that are linked to any discount offer?

Tags: 7, commerce

I created a view (table) of my products and I want to display the ID field of the related discount.

- So I added a relationship with `Trade Discount Offer referencing products from commerce_free_products` and `referencing Trade Discount Trade Discount Offer from commerce_discount_offer`
- Then added the field `Trade Discount: Discount ID` I have my column but in the 0 if I add `(referencing Trade Discount Trade Discount Offer from commerce_discount_offer) Trade Discount: Title for administration (Title for administration)` my column is empty.

What did I do wrong?
I found it [this ticket](https://www.drupal.org/node/2215595) but it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

If by "ID field" you mean the name of the discount shown to customers, this is doable.

You must have a product that is the object of a "Free product" offer.

Once that is done, you'll need to add two relationships to the view. The first, you've already gotten is the link from the product to the offer:

> **Commerce Discount Offer referencing products from commerce_free_products**
>   *Trade Discount Offer referencing products from commerce_free_products*

The other relationship is the link from the offer to the Discount entity itself:

> **Commerce Discount referencing Commerce Discount Offer from commerce_discount_offer**
>
>   *A bridge to the Commerce Discount entity that is referencing Commerce Discount Offer via commerce_discount_offer*

Then you can add fields attached to the *Commerce Discount entity*:

- Commerce Discount: Name
- Commerce Discount: Admin title

And now your labels should be visible.

Comment: thank you for your tutorial, but I want to do this with all products that are linked to a discount offer. Not only free product.

Comment: At this time, it's not supported out of the box.